# How to make a button in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot to update a status message, but I can't get buttons/dropdown menus to work.

I tried:

```
button = discord.Button()
button.custom_id = "test"
button.label = "Label"
button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.primary
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.title = "title"
embed.add_field(name="test",value=button)
```

I got the error:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'update' raised an exception: TypeError: Button.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Comment: it looks like the constructor of Button is expecting a parameter `data` but you are calling the constructor without any parameters

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question you should still post it as an answer & accept it instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a View. Make it like this:

```py
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

You can also make it another way, but that is the way I make it.
Now you made a button, but you have to assign the view to your message where you send the embed.

```py
await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=ButtonView())
await ButtonView().wait()
```

Right now the button doesn't do anything.
Here is an example of how you can make it send a message once you click it:

```py
# Put this inside of the View
@discord.ui.button(label="what is on the button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def function_name(self, int: discord.Interaction):
        await int.response.send_message("button clicked")
```